# What is wrong with my script? I keep getting the error that property could not register

Tags: scripting, error

I have this script here:

```
import bpy


color_options = [
        ('BLACK', "Black", ""),
        ('WHITE', "White", ""),
        ('LIGHT_GREY' "Light Grey", ""),
        ('LIGHT_BLUISH_GREY',"Light Bluish Grey",""),
        ('DARK_GREY', "Dark Grey", ""),
        ('DARK_BLUISH_GREY', "Dark Bluish Grey", ""),
        ('TAN', "Tan", ""),
        ('DARK_TAN', "Dark Tan", ""),
        ('SAND_BLUE', "Sand Blue", ""),
        ('SAND_GREEN', "Sand Green", ""),
        ('DARK_BLUE', "Dark Blue", ""),
        ('DARK_GREEN', "Dark Green", ""),
        ('DARK_BROWN', "Dark Brown", ""),
        ('OLIVE_GREEN', "Olive Green", ""),
        ('YELLOW', "Yellow", ""),
        ('LIGHT_NOUGAT', "Light Nougat", ""),
        ('NOUGAT', "Nougat", ""),
        ('MEDIUM_NOUGAT', "Medium Nougat", ""),
        ('BROWN', "Brown", ""),
        ('REDDISH_BROWN', "Reddish Brown", ""),
        ('RED', "Red", "")
]
    

class minifigure_properties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    texture: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Texture",
        subtype="FILE_PATH"
    )
    head_color: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=color_options,
        name="Head Color",
        default='LIGHT_NOUGAT'
    )


class MinifigureSettingsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Settings"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Minifigure Renderer"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        minifigure_settings = scene.minifigure_settings
        
        # Image texture
        layout.label(text="Image Texture", icon='IMAGE_DATA')
        layout.prop(minifigure_settings, "texture")
        
        # Base colors
        layout.label(text="Base colors", icon='COLOR')
        layout.prop(minifigure_settings, "head_color")


classes = [
    minifigure_properties,
    MinifigureSettingsPanel
]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.minifigure_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=minifigure_properties)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.minifigure_settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

When I try to run this I always get:

```
TypeError: EnumProperty(...): expected a tuple containing (identifier, name, description) and optionally an icon name and unique number
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\minifigure_settings.py", line 82, in <module>
  File "\minifigure_settings.py", line 72, in register
ValueError: bpy_struct "minifigure_properties" registration error: 'head_color' EnumProperty could not register (see previous error)
```

I don't know what the error is! Maybe one of you guys can find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my favorite candidate for the *"Bug of the Month"* award. It was hard to find.

In this line of the *color_options =* ...

```
('LIGHT_GREY' "Light Grey", ""),
```

... the comma between the strings is missing. Python simply merges them into *"LIGHT_GREYLight Grey"* and your tuple has only 2 values instead of the required 3. And then it complains about this, of course, without telling you which tuple is the bad one.

Correct is:

```
('LIGHT_GREY', "Light Grey", ""),
```

Comment: OMG! This is so embarrassing! Thank you :)